# Unable to get custom customer Address attribute value to customer grid

Tags: attributes, admin-panel, magento-2.2.5, customer-attribute, customer-grid

I've created `custom customer address attribute` through `admin panel`. Attribute value is inserting in `customer_address_entity_int` table. I'm able to see `custom attribute` in grid options but **attribute value is not displaying** in  customer grid.

Any Help, Thank you.

Comment: did you run command **php bin/magento indexer:reindex** ??

Comment: Yes, I've done setup:upgrade,  indexer:reindex and cache:flush

Comment: after Customer Grid index you column must show in grid. if you choose it show in customer grid.

Comment: column is showing but value is not coming in customer grid

Comment: @vejitha have you got solution? facing same issue in 2.2.11